# how to check for disk in use on rhel

Tags: linux, rhel, perl

How to check if a disk is in use? If in use, How to check free, used space before I can start using it?

I'm trying this in Perl and Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "a disk in use"?  Are you looking for open files?  Or the disk being mounted somewhere?  Having certain partitions?

Comment: @Bram - I'm looking for disk partitions whilst created as logical volumes under a volume group.

Comment: sorry but I can't make heads or tails of that statement.  Do you want to know which partitions are used as "physical volumes" in a volume group?  Or file systems created on a logical volume?  AFAIK you can't create a partition on a logical volume and it certainly wouldn't make much sense if you could.  Perhaps it helps if you edit your question explaining how you do this manually.  That might make it easier for people to help you script it in any language.

Answer (score 2):

`pvdisplay` will show you which disks and partitions are "in use" for volume-groups

Use `lvs` to get a summary of all configured LVs. LVs that are in use have normally the "**ao**" attribute set. LVs with just "**a**" are *active*, but not currently in use. Use `blkid` to see which filesystems are where. Use `df -h` to see the currently mounted filesystems and their human-readable sizes.

Comment: Huge assumption on OP using LVM.

Comment: I'm will delete my comment, I haven't read the OP's first comment, which clearly describes LV and VG.

Answer (score 2):

I am using next command to check is disk in use:

```
vmstat -d | head -1 ; vmstat -d 1 | grep sda
```

(where is sda disk name)

Answer (score 0):

I always do `lsof | grep file/filesystem` to list open or "in use" files.

Human readable output of "df" might be helpful as well: `df -h /mountpoint`

Answer (score -1):

`fuser -m /path/to/mountpoint` works in shell to show if a disk is use. You could do a system() call from Perl

`df /path/to/mountpoint` tells you about disk space